# How to get column which has least values among them

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE exmp_test
(
id int, 
v1 int,
v2 int,
v3 int,
v4 int
)

SELECT * FROM exmp_test

id  v1  v2  v3  v4
1   2   4   6   7
1   4   77  3   8
```

I want to add the value of the [id] column to (whichever has least value for v1 ,v2 ,v3 ,v4) for each row.

As an example, for the first row, the [id] value should be add to v1 (because it has the lowest value). For the second row, the [id] value should be add to v3 (because it has the lowest value).

How would I write the SQL to do this?

Comment: What should happen if two columns in a row have the same value, and that's the lowest value?

Comment: Then we should go for the left most column. i.e. if v2 and v4 has the same value and it is the least value then we will select v2 column to add the [id] value.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/minimum/.  **(0.5 * ((@ColumnA + @ColumnB) - abs(@ColumnA - @ColumnB)))**

Comment: I dug around to see if there was a built in t-sql function for returning the numeric min of two integers and was surprised that I couldn't find one.  Having min(x,y) would make the query easy, but you would have to write your own tsql function, I suppose.

Comment: This question might be a textbook argument for normalization ... pivot "repeating" columns to rows when designing tables, because the repeating column form makes many types of queries (sum, max, min are just a few) more complicated and slower than necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could normalize the table in a CTE (common table expression), and then select the row with the minimum value.  Based on the comment below your question, I've added priority for v1.

```
;with Normal as (
    select id, v1 as value, 1 as prio from YourTable
    union all select id, v2, 2 as prio from YourTable
    union all select id, v3, 3 as prio from YourTable
    union all select id, v4, 4 as prio from YourTable
)
select top 1 id, value
from Normal
where value = (
    select min(value) from Normal
)
order by prio
```

After re-reading your question, here's a way to look at the lowest value *per row* and add the `id` field to that:

```
update t1
set v1 = v1 + case when mincol = 1 then id else 0 end
,   v2 = v2 + case when mincol = 2 then id else 0 end
,   v3 = v3 + case when mincol = 3 then id else 0 end
,   v4 = v4 + case when mincol = 4 then id else 0 end
from (
    select id, v1, v2, v3, v4,
        case 
          when v1 <= v2 and v1 <= v3 and v1 <= v4 then 1
          when v2 <= v3 and v2 <= v4 then 2
          when v3 <= v4 then 3
          else 4
         end as mincol
    from YourTable
) t1
```

Comment: How can I add the value of [id] to that least value column?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same using UVPIVOT

**Test data**

```
declare @exmp_test table(id int, v1 int,v2 int,v3 int,v4 int)
insert into @exmp_test 
 select 1,   2 ,  4 ,  6,   7 union all
 select 1 ,  4 ,  77 , 3  , 8 union all
 select 2 ,  4 ,  16 , 1  , 8
```

**Query**

```
;with cte as(select row_number() over(order by id) as rn,t.v1 + t.v2 + t.v3 + t.v4 as sumallversions,t.* from @exmp_test t)
    ,unpvtcte as(select rn,id as versions,vals from (select rn,[v1],[v2],[v3],[v4] from cte)t
    unpivot (vals for id in([v1],[v2],[v3],[v4]))as unpvt)
    update @exmp_test
    set id = y.sumall
    from @exmp_test e
    join (
    select c.id,c.id + x.minvals as sumall,c.sumallversions, x.minvals from cte c 
    join(select rn,MIN(vals) minvals from unpvtcte group by rn)x on x.rn = c.rn) y
    on y.id = e.id
    and y.sumallversions = e.v1 + e.v2 + e.v3 + e.v4
```

**Output:**

```
id v1 v2 v3 v4
3 2 4 6 7
4 4 77 3 8
3 4 16 1 8
```